# Custom Property in EPiServer shows in top left corner in Chrome

Tags: episerver, custom-properties

We have created a plugin that shows a custom-property on a page. Until not so long ago, the property showed as a nice square just where I wanted it in edit mode. But now it just shows as a really tiny square in the top left corner in Chrome. All other browsers looks good.

Here is the HTML

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="item" class="epi-overlay-item" id="uniqName_96_0" widgetid="uniqName_96_0" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 0px; height: 0px;">                            
     <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" class="epi-overlay-item-container">                                
         <span data-dojo-attach-point="informationNode" class="epi-overlay-item-info epi-overlay-item-info--inside">jvbimage</span>  
         <div class="epi-overlay-bracket"></div>                             
     </div>                        
</div>
```

As you see, there are som left, right, width, height properties in the #uniqName_96_0 div. But for some reason, the javascript just ignores this. I see that the other properties are resized. Just not my property, except all other browsers than Chrome.

Anyone knows what is going on? I don't think I control this resizing at all, as it is a built in EPiServer thing. So confusing!

Comment: Any chance you could post the editing Dojo class code and template?

Comment: We did not create this plugin. Someone made it for us. And we are no EPiServer Experts (as you might expect). So I am not sure what you are asking for here. the source code for the plugin is here: https://bitbucket.org/fotoware/episerver

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help here.  Do you suspect the `style` attribute of the overlay item is causing the problem?  Perhaps adding something like this to the end of your template will solve the problem. `<script>(function() { document.querySelectorAll(".epi-overlay-item[data-dojo-attach-point=item]")[0].removeAttribute('style'); })();</script>`.  Although, if that's the issue, a better approach would be to determine what is generating the `style` attribute first.